# CORS Issue with AllowAnyOrigin()

Tags: c#, cors

I'm running into a CORS issue in my .NET Core backend. For testing purposes, I'm allowing access for all origins, configured as follows in my service collection:

```
.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddDefaultPolicy(
      builder =>
      {
         builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
      });
})
```

I've also made sure to include `app.UseCors()` in the right order, after `app.UseRouting()` and before `app.UseAuthentication()`.

My service is currently hosted on Azure, and when I use an express proxy to reroute the request from my local application, I don't run into any CORS issues. When I try to hit the desired request URL directly, I run into trouble, which I thought I would avoid by allowing access to all origins.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works for me in dev environments:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    builder
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
        });
```